Draw ellipse in 2D array
I'm trying to draw an ellipse to a 2D array. I have x and y as top left start position and bottom right x and y as end position.
I'm trying to draw an ellipse fitting exactly that rectangle space.
The algorithm I'm using works when the start and end coordinate are even but when the width coord is uneven its one pixel too short and the same for height.
This is my code:
private void DrawEllipse(in NexusCoord start, in NexusCoord end, in NexusChar character)
{
    ThrowIfOutOfBounds(start);
    ThrowIfOutOfBounds(end);
    GetOrThrowColorIndex(character.Foreground, character.Background, nameof(character), out var foregroundColorIndex, out var backgroundColorIndex);

    var glyph = new Glyph(character.Value, foregroundColorIndex, backgroundColorIndex);

    var width = end.X - start.X;
    var height = end.Y - start.Y;

    var centerX = width / 2;
    var centerY = height / 2;

    var radiusX = start.X + centerX;
    var radiusY = start.Y + centerY;

    var x = 0;
    var y = centerY;

    var d1 = centerY * centerY - centerX * centerX * centerY;
    var dx = 2 * centerY * centerY * x;
    var dy = 2 * centerX * centerX * y;

    while (dx < dy)
    {
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(x + radiusX, y + radiusY), glyph);
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(-x + radiusX, y + radiusY), glyph);
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(x + radiusX, -y + radiusY), glyph);
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(-x + radiusX, -y + radiusY), glyph);

        if (d1 < 0)
        {
            x++;
            dx += 2 * centerY * centerY;
            d1 = d1 + dx + centerY * centerY;
        }
        else
        {
            x++;
            y--;
            dx += 2 * centerY * centerY;
            dy -= 2 * centerX * centerX;
            d1 = d1 + dx - dy + centerY * centerY;
        }
    }

    var d2 = centerY * centerY * ((x + 0.5) * (x + 0.5)) + centerX * centerX * ((y - 1) * (y - 1)) - centerX * centerX * centerY * centerY;

    while (y >= 0)
    {
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(x + radiusX, y + radiusY), glyph);
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(-x + radiusX, y + radiusY), glyph);
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(x + radiusX, -y + radiusY), glyph);
        SetGlyph(new NexusCoord(-x + radiusX, -y + radiusY), glyph);

        if (d2 > 0)
        {
            y--;
            dy -= 2 * centerX * centerX;
            d2 = d2 + centerX * centerX - dy;
        }
        else
        {
            y--;
            x++;
            dx += 2 * centerY * centerY;
            dy -= 2 * centerX * centerX;
            d2 = d2 + dx - dy + centerX * centerX;
        }
    }
}

When I'm calling that code to draw it in the console Graphic.DrawShape(NexusShape.Ellipse, new NexusCoord(10, 10), new NexusCoord(45, 35))); it looks like this:

The pink rectangle is the space that should be filled.
I tried using double and rounding but that didn't work either.

I fixed it by using a workaround. I'm now creating a bitmap at the size the ellipse should be and draw an ellipse with GDI+ Graphics on it. Then I iterate the pixels and put it in the 2D array. It's not as fast as calculating myself but that obviously didn't work so that's my solution now.

Well, I am no expert in C#, but if var type is an implicit type definition, then you should be careful with it. When you evaluate the center coordinates in the following section:
var centerX = width / 2;
var centerY = height / 2;

You end up with integers. So, in your example:
centerX = 17
centerY = 12

instead of:
centerX = 17.5
centerY = 12.5

So, either you carefully and explicitely define your variables types throughout your code, or you can modify your code this way:
var centerX = width / 2.0;
var centerY = height / 2.0;

This will force these variables to be considered as doubles. You may need to implement this "trick" at different places in your code.

I tried that as well but then the ellipse in one pixel to wide.

When I round down it's too small if I round up it's too large.

In that case, if you are sure the computed coordinates are correct, then is it not the drawing function that is "failing"? I guess this is SetGlyph()? Could you provide information regarding this function?

With that method everything is right. I use it for many more drawing operations (like drawing the rectangle) and they work perfectly.
